# How can I log every printed output while printing inside an (external) function

Tags: python, logging

I am not so familiar with logger; please allow me to ask.

Basically I want to log everything I print. The problem is that the print lines are inside functions declared in external files. For example, my `main.py` file is like

```
from do_run import do_run
import logging
if __name__ == "__main__":

    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, format='%(message)s')
    logger = logging.getLogger()
    logger.addHandler(logging.FileHandler('test.log', 'a'))
    global print
    print = logger.info
    do_run()
```

And I have printing lines in the do_run() function defined in a separate python file `do_run.py`:

```
def do_run():

    print('blah')
```

The problem is that 'blah' is not printed in the 'test.log' file, whlie I want it to be printed in it.

Is there a simple way to fix it?

Comment: don't override the built-in `print` function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kind of hack-y but you can use `patch` from `unittest.mock` in order to have it log to the file as well as print.

```
from src.do_run import do_run
import logging
from unittest.mock import patch

if __name__ == "__main__":
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, format='%(message)s')
    logger = logging.getLogger()
    logger.addHandler(logging.FileHandler('test.log', 'a'))
    with patch("src.do_run.print", logger.info):
        do_run()
```

When I run the above code I get a `test.log` file with the contents of `blah` in it.